# Java Spring Boot return 404

Tags: java, spring-boot

Spring Boot application runs normally on embedded Tomcat server when I run it from Eclipse, but when I deploy it to external tomcat server (on Windows) I'm getting HTTP 404 status.

I did clean package and copied from target folder war file in tomcat webapps folder on local tomcat server and I restarted tomcat but...

When I run get method in postman with endpoint http://localhost:8080/export/test/
I get 404 not found

Tomcat version 9
Java 11

**TOMCAT MANAGER:**

[image]

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExportApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExportApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(ExportApplication.class);
    }
}
```

**POM file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>bojankosta</groupId>
    <artifactId>export</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>export</name>
    <description>Export db</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties:**

```
server.servlet.context-path=/export
```

**Controller:**

```
package bojankosta.export.controller;

import bojankosta.export.service.ContinentService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class BasicController {

       @Autowired
       private ContinentService continentService;

       @GetMapping("/")
       public String getAllData()  {
              return continentService.export();
       }

       @GetMapping("/test")
       @ResponseBody
       public String currentUserName() {
              return "Hello";
       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

404 means that url you are hitting is not available.When We deploy the code on  external application server it serves it from root context that is generally start with the project name .
You can check in the logs what is context it is serving and then append the rest end point it .It will work

Comment: It should be like filename "export"

Comment: Can you send me some simple war file or project to test is it going to work when I copy it on my local tomcat

Comment: You need to set the application context in tomcat and it can be done by following steps -- Edit Configuration --> tomcatServer( the tomcat server you are using) ->under that go to deployment tab -> you will find Application context for your war deployed -> set it to /export .

Answer (score 0):

You can use finalName property in your build file (pom.xml for maven)

```
<finalName>export</finalName>
```

Comment: I did that <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>