# spring boot application on apache tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, war

i try to take my spring boot application create war file and deploy to my tomcat server (port 8080)
there was a problem that after deploy i got HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

so i create clean spring boot application (via https://start.spring.io with dev and web dependencies and java 11
i add a small controller end service:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin()
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/jobs")
    String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
```

i add the following to the pom:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
 <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

and also

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

in my spring application i add the extend from SpringBootServletInitializer :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
 }
 @Override
 protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
 return builder.sources(DemoApplication.class);
 }
}
```

via maven i run mvn package
the created war (first.war) i deploy via the appachi tomcat manager
than i go to the apllication url:
http://localhost:8080/first/jobs  (jobs is one of the end service in the controller)
and i got HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

the tomcat version is 9.0.56
any idea ?
what am i misssing

Comment: Similar question on this trace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70650616/java-spring-boot-return-404/70650679?noredirect=1#comment124906922_70650679

Comment: its didnt help i enter to http://localhost:8080/keystone-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/jobs the keystone-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is the name of the deployment and what written in the manager , and jobs is the end service- still got the 404 error response